# Why is Live View overexposed on my Nikon D5600?

Tags: nikon, live-view, nikon-d5600

I am pretty sure live view was working normally. But for a few days, I realized if I switch to Live View mode, then the images shown in the Live View are so bright that I can't even see the subject (but the captured image looks fine, which depends on my aperture, focus etc.).

If I press the shutter button to focus, then the exposure in the Live Viewer becomes okay for a moment and then the image again becomes too bright.

Answer (score 2):

Checkout your screen brightness in the menu option!

Comment: OP's second paragraph denotes its not the screen brightness, "...becomes okay for a moment."

Answer (score 0):

Your aperture is wide open until you take the photo. If you have a button to preview the brightness, pressing it will cause the aperture will stop down while viewing.
Maybe you are using a high ISO which sets the sensor to high sensitivity?

Answer (score 0):

I've had a D5600 for several years. I just ran into this exact same problem. It is the exposure compensation value that is set to 5.0 and it is stuck there. Go into live view and then hit the lowercase "i" button on the back top right of the body. Then the exposure compensation adjustment button is on the screen in the lower right hand corner. It probably says 5.0 on it. You need to adjust that back down to zero and then your live view will be normal again.